Control feature order or z-index for WebGL layer icons? (OpenLayers)
I want to control the order icons appear on a WebGL layer so icons in the north appear in the back and overlap to the front as they appear southwards.
Since the WebGL layer does not have a renderOrder function, I tried to do this by applying sort() to the imported geographical data, assigning a 'z-index' value to each feature, then using a style expression to grab the 'z-index' property, but it has no effect.
Is this a bug or is there a correct way to achieve what I want, if it's even possible?
Example: https://jsfiddle.net/Sidders/z2fay46d/
Relevant code:
parsed_data = new ol.format.GeoJSON().readFeatures(data,{
  dataProjection: "EPSG:4326",
  featureProjection: "EPSG:3857",
});
    
parsed_data.sort((a, b) => {
    b.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[1] - a.getGeometry().getCoordinates()[1];
});
    
//Add z-index property
parsed_data.forEach((feature, index) => {
  feature.set("zIndex", index);
});

const webGLstyle = [{
      //Stuff
      'z-index': ['get', 'zIndex']
    }]


There was a request to implement this (see https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/issues/10634), but it doesn't seem to be implemented.

Ah, I saw this but assumed it must have been implemented since then, but I guess not! Thank you for the link
